why object.keys reading keys from middle of an object
I have an object


 let files = {
            '00':{},
            '01':{},
            '02':{},
            '03':{},
            '04':{},
            '05':{},
            '06':{},
            '07':{},
            '08':{},
            '09':{},
            '10':{},
            '11':{},
            '12':{},
            '13':{},
            '14':{},
            '15':{}
        }

console.log(Object.keys(files))



the result I'm getting is this.
["10","11","12","13","14","15","00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09"]

1. why it's reading key from 10 not from 00 ?
2. How to make it read from zero i.e first key of an object ?

@JSONDerulo we cannot use array now, it's object and somehow I need to achieve this. Also the key may be a string sometimes.

You need to process your object in the order by sorted Object.keys() where you sort the way YOU want

Do you have only two-digit numbers or can you have something like 100 and 20? If all numbers have the same number of digits, you can lexicographically sort. If you have number with different number of digits, it's more complex.

This is because of the order of execution of Object Keys in JS:
Numbers -> Strings -> Symbols
And in case of Strings, JS checks if they can be converted to Numbers.
Eg: "10" can be converted to 10, but "00" can't be.
That's why you see ["10","11","12","13","14","15","00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09"]
References:

https://dev.to/frehner/the-order-of-js-object-keys-458d
https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/


This answer's the first question

Then to make it forcefully read. we, must stop object.keys to convert something into number/symbol. but how?

You cannot. But you can sort it yourself, or perhaps store all keys with a letter as prefix.

JavaScript object properties have a strict pre-defined order, which you cannot change. The obvious fix would be to use an Array instead, because arrays are designed to handle a custom order, unlike objects. If this is not an option for you, the only way is to sort the array returned by Object.keys():


const files = {
  '00': {},
  '01': {},
  '02': {},
  '03': {},
  '04': {},
  '05': {},
  '06': {},
  '07': {},
  '08': {},
  '09': {},
  '10': {},
  '11': {},
  '12': {},
  '13': {},
  '14': {},
  '15': {},
};

console.log(Object.keys(files).sort());



